# PHP will generate jpg images from BLOB but not from LONGBLOB in MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, image, blob

The following script has been outputting images from a BLOB column in MySQL for a good time now:

```
<?
$dbname="usr_web5_1";
$db = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname);
$sql = "SELECT foto, fototype, modified FROM `Komplettverzeichnis_extras` WHERE `WPID`= ?";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("s",$_GET['id']);
if (!$stmt->execute()) $error=true;
$stmt->bind_result($file,$filetype,$modified);
$stmt->fetch();
if (!isset($filetype)) $filetype = "image/jpeg";
if (!$error) {
    header("Content-type: $filetype;");
    header("Last-Modified: $modified;");
} else {
    echo "Error";
    echo $db->error;
}
echo $file;
$stmt->close();
$db->close();
}
?>
```

I have tried both altering the column to LONGBLOB and replacing it by a new LONGBLOB colument; the images will not show. This is regardless wether I try to show the images already in place or I try and upload new ones.

The closest problem I found is [here](http://www.php.de/datenbanken/56791-erledigt-longblob-akzeptiert-kein-binary-attribut.html) (german). For altering the column I used

```
ALTER TABLE `Komplettverzeichnis_extras` CHANGE `foto` `foto` LONGBLOB DEFAULT NULL
```

Obviously I am willing to provide more information if necessary.

I use phpMyAdmin in version 3.5.2.2, PHP 5.3.17, and mysql client API version (is that the mysql version?) 5.1.63.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the data in a LONGBLOB might be too large for your default mysql server client connection and requires some configuration so that you can send large amounts of data (maxpackets or something similarly named). Compare binary lengths first because if those differ you already know that the data has been truncated, often a sign for some kind of limit.

Comment: Thank you. However, it does not work when I use files that have worked perfectly in the BLOB version. Thus, nothing is truncated.

Comment: Please add the original table definition to your question so that it is visible from what state you alter the table.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured out the problem:

For a BLOB, the mySQLi Methods for strings will work that are used in my code as you can see above. This is not the case for Longblob. After the execute() and before the bind_result(), a store_result() is necessariy. Also, When saving, I cannot simply use bind_param(). Instead, the following construction using a NULL has to be used:

```
if (!$stmt = $db->prepare($sql)) printf($db->error);
$null = NULL;
$stmt->bind_param("bsi",$null,$type,$id);
$stmt->send_long_data(0,$data);
if (!$stmt->execute()) printf($db->error);
$stmt->close();
```

To cut it short, the following ressource helped me out:
[Oswald@Work](https://blogs.oracle.com/oswald/entry/php_s_mysqli_extension_storing)

Thank you all anyway for your efforts!